# Filtering lists

Tags: python, list, unique

I want to filter repeated elements in my list
for instance

```
foo = ['a','b','c','a','b','d','a','d']
```

I am only interested with:

```
['a','b','c','d']
```

What would be the efficient way to do achieve this ?
Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cast foo to a [set](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set), if you don't care about element order.

Comment: sri has beaten you by 2 seconds :p

Comment: @Helinar: that's not true, fatcat1111 was faster by 1 second

Comment: yep, i think fatcat1111 was a second faster than me, so you should accept the above answer if helps you equally as mine :-)

Comment: @sri - Your answer offers more information - it shows a code example (however brief) and mentions the 2.5+ requirement.

Comment: There is no "cast". Perhaps you mean "coerce".

Comment: @pst - Thanks, I've never been completely clear on the difference there. IIRC, values (not symbols/variables) have types, and are cast; one coerces variables. Or is it the other way around? Looks like I have a SO question here!

Answer (score 21):

`list(`[`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set)`(foo))` if you are using Python 2.5 or greater, but that doesn't maintain order.

Answer (score 5):

Since there isn't an order-preserving answer with a list comprehension, I propose the following:

```
>>> temp = set()
>>> [c for c in foo if c not in temp and (temp.add(c) or True)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

which could also be written as

```
>>> temp = set()
>>> filter(lambda c: c not in temp and (temp.add(c) or True), foo)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Depending on how many elements are in `foo`, you might have faster results through repeated hash lookups instead of repeated iterative searches through a temporary list.

`c not in temp` verifies that `temp` does not have an item `c`; and the `or True` part forces `c` to be emitted to the output list when the item is added to the set.

Comment: Why store items that have been found already in a hash of `None`s instead of a `set`?

Comment: Because I didn't think that one through all the way.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> bar = []
>>> for i in foo:
    if i not in bar:
        bar.append(i)

>>> bar
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

this would be the most straightforward way of removing duplicates from the list and preserving the order as much as possible (even though "order" here is inherently wrong concept).

Comment: Should at least mention the O(n^2) performance characteristic, no?

Comment: @SilentGhost - What's `k` there? Is it a constant (i.e. not part of Big-O notation) or is it some other factor?

Comment: I don't think it's O(n^2). It may be O(not very good), but it's not _that_ bad.

Comment: @Chris - I believe Triptych and hughdbrown are pointing out the append operation on bar is likely not constant time (a quick but unmotivated docs.python.org check didn't find much). And I do think SilentGhost meant a constant.

Comment: Never mind.  I totally missed the membership test in the if statement the first seven or so times I read the function.  Yep, O(n^2).

Comment: what pbh said. Membership test in a list is O(n). That * the loop = O(n^2). This page is helpful: http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: what I was referring to is that `bar` and `foo` have different size. it would be `n**2` only if `foo` doesn't have any duplicates, it's better otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

If you care about order a readable way is the following

```
def filter_unique(a_list):
    characters = set()
    result = []
    for c in a_list:
        if not c in characters:
            characters.add(c)
            result.append(c)
    return result
```

Depending on your requirements of speed, maintanability, space consumption, you could find the above unfitting. In that case, specify your requirements and we can try to do better :-)

Comment: +1 Your answer inspired me to create a class that allows using the built-in `filter()` to do the same thing. So thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: @Chris: My pleasure :-)

I thought that using filter would have been slightly more advanced and so went for a very simple solution. 

If you like filter consider using the (excellent) module itertools and in particular itertools.ifilter and itertools.ifilterfalse

Answer (score 2):

If you write a function to do this i would use a generator, it just wants to be used in this case.

```
def unique(iterable):
    yielded = set()
    for item in iterable:
        if item not in yielded:
            yield item
            yielded.add(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Francesco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596390/filtering-lists-in-python/1596435#1596435), rather than making our own `filter()`-type function, let's make the builtin do some work for us:

```
def unique(a, s=set()):
    if a not in s:
        s.add(a)
        return True
    return False
```

Usage:

```
uniq = filter(unique, orig)
```

This may or may not perform faster or slower than an answer that implements all of the work in pure Python. Benchmark and see. Of course, this only works once, but it demonstrates the concept. The ideal solution is, of course, to use a class:

```
class Unique(set):
    def __call__(self, a):
        if a not in self:
            self.add(a)
            return True
        return False
```

Now we can use it as much as we want:

```
uniq = filter(Unique(), orig)
```

Once again, we may (or may not) have thrown performance out the window - the gains of using a built-in function may be offset by the overhead of a class. I just though it was an interesting idea.

Comment: What happens if you run this twice? `uniq = filter(Unique(), range(10)); print uniq`

Comment: Actually, I meant if you run this twice: `uniq = filter(unique, range(10)); print uniq`

Comment: The `unique` version only works once. Running it a second time on the same data will produce no data, because the function only has one set (the second argument). Running it twice on different data can produce unexpected results, as it will weed out the overlap of the two data sets as well as the duplicates of the second set. The function was my first version, and its limitations led me to create the class version, which suffers no such problems (and is also more generally useful). The function version was shown as a thought-process thing, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want if you need a sorted list at the end:

```
>>> foo = ['a','b','c','a','b','d','a','d']
>>> bar = sorted(set(foo))
>>> bar
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: list comprehension is redundant.  could just say: bar = sorted(set(foo))

Comment: Nice answer -- answers the question directly (although not entirely honestly IMOHO) which has output in natural ordering. +1.

Comment: @pst: Not entirely honestly? Like I am trying to pull something over on you? Or...what? I don't get where the OP asked for a stable sort, so I just sorted them because it looked like that *was* a requirement. @recursive: good call. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
np.unique(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a sort of ugly list comprehension hack.

```
[l[i] for i in range(len(l)) if l.index(l[i]) == i]
```