# Find unique numbers in a file from a line of three number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I read a file in python, which contains in each line 2 integer numbers and 1 real.
How can i find in **python** the number of unique number from the 2 first integer number from all the file (except real)?

eg file

```
1 2 3.3
11 22 33.3
111 222 333.3
11 22 33.3
114 224 334.4
```

In this example, the result should be 8.

UPDATE
this is my code

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
           print(word)
```

How can I determine not to consider the **real** number and after i can do **count** **distinct** number from the first **two integer** in each line

Comment: Please show what you have tried and which problems did you encounter. This way you have more chances to get help and less chances to get downvotes

Comment: You read in the file line by line, split the line at spaces using `split()` . You convert the resulting strings into numbers, feed them into a set and check how big the set gets. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is a question about several things: file reading, filtering, counting. Please show your attempt and which of these things you have trouble with (just one). But I'm quite sure it will turn out to be a question that has been asked before.

Comment: Check: [How to read a file line by line into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277503/5459839),
[How to split a string into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/743806/5459839),
[How to filter lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1596390/5459839),
[How do I count unique values inside a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12282232/5459839)

Comment: i have update my question with my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) function to generate a unique set. For example:

```
fileName = 'test.txt'
with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
    unique = set()
    for line in f.readlines():
        unique = unique | set(line.split()[:2])
print(unique)
```

Output:

```
{'114', '11', '22', '111', '2', '224', '222', '1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading your file, you can get the set of every flattened row slices `[:2]`, then get the length:

```
from itertools import chain

with open('numbers.txt') as file:
    unique = len(set(chain.from_iterable(x.split()[:2] for x in file)))
    print(unique)

# 8
```